# How to develop ios apps on outdated hardware?

Tags: ios, xcode, development

I have an old MacBook Pro 15“ from Mid 2012.
Latest OS: Catalina
Latest XCode: 12.4 (https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)
And an iPhone 8 with iOS 16.1.1.

I saw that the minimal requirements for submitting iOS Apps to the Appstore is XCode 13 as of 25 April, 2022 (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=2t1chhp3).

What can I do with minimal cost to build iOS apps for the Appstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 13 requires macOS 11 Big Sur.

[OpenCore Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/) is free and [supports 2012 MacBook Pro models](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MODELS.html#macbook-pro) enabling them to run unsupported versions of macOS, including macOS 11 and newer.

Once you are running at least macOS 11 you can download and run Xcode normally.

Comment: That looks promising, and I found this thread, because I was worried for safety issues: https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/xxagm5/is_the_open_core_legacy_patcher_secure/.

Comment: @1uk System Integrity Protection is just one of numerous security features, so while disabling it does reduce the overall security of the machine, it's not like that single feature makes the entire system immediately vulnerable to every attack. OCLP is popular, made by reputable developers, and is open source: https://github.com/dortania/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher